# sobrecarregamento da thread android

Tags: android, thread

Estou fazendo um jogo da velha para Android, fiz seguindo o livro que eu tenho.

O exemplo ensina a criar a logica do jogo para dois jogadores jogar no mesmo celular, funcionou corretamente, mas o exemplo só ensina criar uma tela que vai direto para o jogo, mas eu implementei uma tela para ser usada de menu, foi ai que o app parou de funcionar.

Tudo indica que esta sobrecarregando a `thread` principal, foi ai que eu pesquisei e vi que posso criar uma nova `thread`, mas não consegui fazer, se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda eu agradeço.

**Detalhes do projeto:**

As `activity` criadas são: *Jogo.java*, *MainActivity.java*, *JogoDaVelhaView.java*

**Jogo.java**

```
package teste.app.android.jogodavelha;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Jogo extends AppCompatActivity implements JogoDaVelhaView.JogoDaVelhaListener,JogoDaVelhaView.OnClickListener {
JogoDaVelhaView jogo;
private static final String Categoria = “Script”;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jogo);
    jogo = (JogoDaVelhaView) findViewById(R.id.JogoDaVelha);
    jogo.setListener(this);

    Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onCreate();");


    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onStart();");
}

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onRestart();");
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onResume();");
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onPause();");
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onStop();");
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onDestroy();");
}


private String getClassName() {
    String aux = getClass().getName();
    return (aux.substring(aux.indexOf(".") + 1));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    jogo.reiniciarJogo();
}

@Override
public void fimDeJogo(int vencedor) {

    String mensagem;
    switch (vencedor){
    case JogoDaVelhaView.XIS:
    mensagem="X venceu!";
    break;
    case JogoDaVelhaView.BOLA:
    mensagem="O venceu!";
    break;
default:
mensagem=“Empatou”;

    }
    Toast.makeText(this,mensagem,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package teste.app.android.jogodavelha;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btJogar;
private static final String Categoria = “Script”;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + “.onCreate();”);
chamaMenu();

    btJogar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_jogar);
    ;
    btJogar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chamaJogo();
        }
    });
}
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(Categoria,getClassName()+".onStart();");
    }
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onRestart();");
    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onResume();");
    }
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onPause();");
    }
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onStop();");
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(Categoria, getClassName() + ".onDestroy();");
    }




protected void chamaJogo() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jogo);
}

protected void chamaMenu() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
private String getClassName() {
    String aux = getClass().getName();
    return (aux.substring(aux.indexOf(".") + 1));
}
}
```

**JogoDaVelhaView.java**

```
package teste.app.android.jogodavelha;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**

Created by Pablo on 23/12/2017.
*/
public class JogoDaVelhaView extends View {

private boolean ganhou(int a, int b , int c){
    return (a ==b && b==c && a !=VAZIO);
}
int mCorDaBarra;
float mLarguraDaBarra;


public void reiniciarJogo() {
    mTabuleiro = new int[3][3];
    invalidate();
}
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState(){
    Parcelable p = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    EstadoJogo estado = new EstadoJogo(p,mVez,mTabuleiro);
    return estado;



}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state){
    EstadoJogo estado = (EstadoJogo) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(estado.getSuperState());
    mVez =estado.vez;
    mTabuleiro = estado.tabuleiro;
    invalidate();


}
static class EstadoJogo extends BaseSavedState{
    int vez;
    int[][] tabuleiro;

    private EstadoJogo(Parcelable p , int vez, int [][] tabuleiro){
        super(p);
        this.vez = vez;
        this.tabuleiro = tabuleiro;
    }
    private EstadoJogo(Parcel p){
        super(p);
        vez = p.readInt();
        tabuleiro = new int[3][3];
        for (int linha = 0; linha <tabuleiro.length;linha++){
            p.readIntArray(tabuleiro[linha]);
        }
    }
    public final Parcelable.Creator<EstadoJogo>
    Creator = new Parcelable.Creator<EstadoJogo>(){
        public EstadoJogo createFromParcel(Parcel in){
            return new EstadoJogo(in);

        }
        public EstadoJogo[] newArray(int size){
            return new EstadoJogo[size];
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel,int flags){
        super.writeToParcel(parcel, flags);
        parcel.writeInt(vez);
        for (int linha =0;linha <tabuleiro.length;linha++){
            parcel.writeIntArray(tabuleiro[linha]);
        }
    }
}
public interface JogoDaVelhaListener{
    void fimDeJogo(int vencedor);

}

public JogoDaVelhaView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    mVez = XIS;
    mTabuleiro = new int[3][3];

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.JogoDaVelha);
    mCorDaBarra = a.getColor(R.styleable.JogoDaVelha_corDaBarra, Color.BLACK);
    mLarguraDaBarra = a.getDimension(R.styleable.JogoDaVelha_larguraDaBarra, 3);

}

public static final int XIS = 1;
public static final int BOLA = 2;
private static final int VAZIO = 0;
public static final int EMPATE = 3;

int mTamanho;
int mVez;
int [][] mTabuleiro;
Paint mPaint;
Bitmap mImageX;
Bitmap mImageO;
GestureDetector mDetector;
JogoDaVelhaListener mListener;

public void setListener(JogoDaVelhaListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}
private int gameOver(){
    //horizontais
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[0][0],mTabuleiro[0][1],mTabuleiro[0][2])) {
        return mTabuleiro[0][0];
    }
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[1][0],mTabuleiro[1][1],mTabuleiro[1][2])) {
        return mTabuleiro[1][0];
    }
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[2][0],mTabuleiro[2][1],mTabuleiro[2][2])) {
        return mTabuleiro[2][0];
    }
    //verticais
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[0][0],mTabuleiro[0][1],mTabuleiro[0][2])) {
        return mTabuleiro[0][0];
    }
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[0][1],mTabuleiro[1][1],mTabuleiro[2][1])) {
        return mTabuleiro[0][1];
    }
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[0][2],mTabuleiro[1][2],mTabuleiro[2][2])) {
        return mTabuleiro[0][2];
    }
    //diagonais
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[0][0],mTabuleiro[1][1],mTabuleiro[2][2])) {
        return mTabuleiro[0][0];
    }
    if (ganhou(mTabuleiro[0][2],mTabuleiro[1][1],mTabuleiro[2][0])) {
        return mTabuleiro[0][2];
    }
    //Existem espaço vazios
    for (int linha =0;linha <mTabuleiro.length;linha++){
        for (int coluna =0;
                coluna < mTabuleiro[linha].length;coluna++){
            if (mTabuleiro[linha][coluna] == VAZIO){
                return VAZIO;
            }
        }
    }
    return EMPATE;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow(){
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    mDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getContext(), new VelhaTouchListener());
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mImageX = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.x_mark);
    mImageO = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.o_mark);

}
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    mTabuleiro = null;
    mPaint = null;
    mImageX = null;
    mImageO = null;
    mDetector = null;
}
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
class VelhaTouchListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e){
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event){
int vencedor = gameOver();

    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && vencedor ==VAZIO){
        int quadrante =mTamanho/3;
        int linha =(int)(event.getY() / quadrante);
        int coluna =(int)(event.getX() / quadrante);

        if (mTabuleiro[linha][coluna]==VAZIO){
            mTabuleiro[linha][coluna]= mVez;
            mVez =(mVez ==XIS)?BOLA :XIS;
            invalidate();

            vencedor = gameOver();
            if (vencedor !=VAZIO){
                if (mListener != null){
                    mListener.fimDeJogo(vencedor);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onSingleTapUp(event);
}
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    if (getLayoutParams().width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT){
        Resources r = getResources();
        float quadrante = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,48,r.getDisplayMetrics());
        mTamanho = (int) quadrante * 3;

    }else if(getLayoutParams().width== ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT){
        mTamanho = Math.min(
                MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
                MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));

    }else {
        mTamanho = getLayoutParams().width;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(mTamanho,mTamanho);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int quadrante = mTamanho /3;

    //Desenhando as linhas
    mPaint.setColor(mCorDaBarra);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mLarguraDaBarra);

    //Verticais
    canvas.drawLine(quadrante,0,quadrante,mTamanho,mPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(quadrante* 2,0,quadrante*2,mTamanho,mPaint);

    //Horizontais
    canvas.drawLine(0,quadrante,mTamanho,quadrante,mPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0,quadrante* 2,mTamanho,quadrante*2,mPaint);

    for (int linha =0; linha<3;linha++){
        for (int coluna =0; coluna <3; coluna++){
            int x = coluna * quadrante;
            int y = linha * quadrante;
            Rect rect = new Rect(x,y,x+ quadrante,y +quadrante);

            if (mTabuleiro[linha][coluna] ==XIS){
                canvas.drawBitmap(mImageX,null,rect,null);

            }else if (mTabuleiro[linha][coluna] ==BOLA) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mImageO,null,rect,null);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seria melhor você editar sua pargunta apresentando apenas os trechos do seu código que são relevantes ao problema.

Comment: Não é necessário criar uma nova `thread`, na verdade não faz sentido esse `setContentView` para exibir o menu. Para esse caso, a melhor opção é utilizar `fragments`. Você pode ler mais em https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html. Ou então você poderá criar uma nova `activity`. Leia mais em: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=pt-br